# Recognizing edits in maven modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Use Intellij 2017.2.2 IDE. I have multiple maven module in a project. If i add a method in module1, to see the method in module2. I firstly have to build module1, then i will be able to see new added method in module2. Is there a option in intellij for this?

Comment: How did you configure the dependencies between the modules? Snapshot dependencies should be resolved via project without the need to compile.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>modeul1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency> @CrazyCoder

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "build"? `mvn install` or Build | Build in IntelliJ IDEA? It would really help to find the problem if you could share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder in intellij, i added maven configuration which builds all project using maven command. the maven command is "mvn install".

Comment: It means that the dependencies are resolved via libraries, not via modules. If both modules are open in IntelliJ IDEA within the same project, it should resolved via sources, not via libraries in the Maven repository. Therefore we'd like to see a sample project to analyze why it happens in your configuration.